# specificity of declarations vs browser's for a

Tags: css, css-specificity

for instance if we have a css

```
#toolbar {color: white; background: black;}
```

and we know the specificity is `0,1,0,0`

and toolbar has some links.

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <a href="#link">Link1</a>
</div>
```

and probably the browser stylesheet says

```
 a:link {color: blue;}
```

hence specificity `0,0,1,0`

in that case our style for color should have won against browser's, but why links still get blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule applies to `#toolbar`. The browser's rule applies to `a`. If you want to inherit your `#toolbar` rule, you could say

```
a:link { color: inherit; }
```

Specificity works on an element-by-element basis. A high-specificity rule on a parent has no specificity-related impact on a child. Even an `!important` on a parent would not affect the specificity calculation for the child directly. The exception would be when the property is inheritable (meaning the child has an implicit `property: inherit;` setting), and there is no explicit rule (including in the browser stylesheet) applying to that property for the child.